# Add library to Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

In my Eclipse Plugin I have a table that shows Integer and String values. To edit the String values I'm using a `TextCellEditor` which is in the package `org.eclipse.jface.viewers`.

I have found a [`NumberCellEditor`](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/eclipse-doc36/org/eclipse/ve/internal/propertysheet/NumberCellEditor.html) which I want to try. It is in the package `org.eclipse.ve.internal.propertysheet.NumberCellEditor`.

I cannot see this package in eclipse it is not listed in the plugin.xml file under `Dependencies`. It's not in the list that shows up when clicking the "Add"-Button either.

How can I use this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.eclipse.ve` appears to be the old Eclipse Visual Editor plugin which is no longer available.

Additionally classes in a package with `internal` in the name are off-limits (see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)). They may be changed or removed at any time.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. I don't understand why there is no jface NumberCellEditor (or any CellEditor that handles Numbers).